# How to treat member of Num typeclass as an Int

Tags: haskell

This is a function I'm trying to write:

```
missingNumber :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
missingNumber list = (sum refList) - (sum list)
  where refList = [1..n]
        n = length list
```

Given a list of numbers, I want to sum them and compare them to a known list to see if any are missing. This code seems straightforward, but when I run it I get this (rather verbose) error:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Int)
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the type signature for missingNumber :: Num a => [a] -> a
  at missingnumber.hs:1:18-36
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for missingNumber :: Num a => [a] -> a
      at missingnumber.hs:1:18
Expected type: [a]
  Actual type: [Int]
In the first argument of `sum', namely `refList'
In the first argument of `(-)', namely `(sum refList)'
In the expression: (sum refList) - (sum list)
```

I'm guessing this is happening because `n` in `[1..n]` must be an instance of the `Enum` type class in order to be iterated over in sequence. But (assuming I'm correct), how do I cast `a` as two types? Also... shouldn't `Int` be a member of the Num class?

Comment: you can use `fromIntegral n` but if `[1..n]` should work you need `Enum a` so you could use `[1..toEnum n]` too (don't forget the `Enum a` in `(Num a, Enum a)`

Comment: as an alternative (you just need the sum) you can use `fromIntegral (sum list)` instead and don't need the `Enum` at all

Comment: But can you explain why this doesn't compile? @Carsten

Comment: also note that it will not work with `n = length list` ;)

Comment: Why won't it work?

Comment: this does not compile because `(-)` needs two arguments of the same type - so `sum list` has to be `a` too - but then `n` needs to be `a` too

Comment: it will not work because `length [1,2,4] == 3` but then you do `sum [1,2,3]` but you need `sum [1,2,3,4]` ;)

Comment: Aren't `Ints` Numbers?

Comment: I don't understand.. can you please post an answer with working code?

Comment: yes but you claim that your algorithm works for **all** numbers `a` - and `Int` is just one of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114473/discussion-between-dopatraman-and-carsten).

Answer (score 1):

as you asked this should work:

```
missing :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
missing xs = fromIntegral (sum [1..length xs + 1]) - sum xs
```

but only if your list of numbers is just missing one number in `[1..m]` for some `m`

---

your version don't work because you claim

```
missingNumber :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
```

and then it needs to work for all `Num a` - for example `Double` - but then you will mix `Int` with `Double` (for example) - which you cannot do

`fromIntegral` saves you here because it will bring back your `Int` into any `Num a` you might have there (it's `fromIntegral :: (Integral c, Num d) => c -> d` - here you have `c ~ Int` and `d ~ a` - where `~` means type-equality)

Comment: What is the signature for `missing`?

Comment: I added it - but you can really check it for yourself using GHCi (actually you'll learn more if you do  those things yourself) - if you don't understand `Foldable t` yet read it like `missing :: Num a => [a] -> a` - so it's exactly what you wanted)